# How to use ng-repeat to iterate same values and bind it in ul

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

From Datatable i am getting list below

```
$scope.Course = [
    { CourseHeading: 'Course1', subcourse: 'A' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course1', subcourse: 'B' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course2', subcourse: 'A' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course2', subcourse: 'B' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course3', subcourse: 'D' }]
```

i want result like this
`CourseHeading:Course1
subcourse:A, B
CourseHeading:Course2
subcourse:A, B
CourseHeading:Course3
subcourse:D`

how can i use `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `angular.filter` module, [**angular.filter**](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.Course = [
    { CourseHeading: 'Course1', subcourse: 'A' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course1', subcourse: 'B' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course2', subcourse: 'A' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course2', subcourse: 'B' },
    { CourseHeading: 'Course3', subcourse: 'D' }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
     <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.1/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in Course | groupBy: 'CourseHeading'">
        CourseHeading: {{ key }}
         
       <div style="margin-left:10px;">SubCourse: <span ng-repeat="subValue in value">{{subValue.subcourse}}{{($index < value.length - 1 ? ", " : "")}}</span></div>
      </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: To output with commas instead of each subcourse on a separate line you can change your second `ng-repeat` to something like: `<div style="margin-left:10px;">SubCourse: <span ng-repeat="subValue in value">{{subValue.subcourse}}{{($index < value.length - 1 ? ", " : "")}}</span></div>`

Comment: what in case of data returning from httpget?  $scope.Course = data; Json.Stringify(data) is                                                                                         `[{ "CourseHeading": "Course1", "subcourse": "A" },
 { "CourseHeading": "Course1", "subcourse": "B" },
 { "CourseHeading": "Course2", "subcourse": "A" },
 { "CourseHeading": "Course2", "subcourse": "B" },
 { "CourseHeading": "Course3", "subcourse": "D" }] `